# Find all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $2^a+5^b$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

How do you solve such questions when they appear?

I know that this problem involves quadratic residues. Moreover, I also know that a=2,b=1 is possible. It may also be the only solution

I tried to take $\pmod{5}$ of this equation but it didn't really help me. I would appreciate if someone could post a solution to this problem.

Thank You

Comment: What is your definition of a perfect square number? Because in your example $2^3+5^1=8+5=13$ which is not even a square number..

Comment: I actually did not mean to put that there. My bad. I wanted to put a=2, b=1

Comment: So by a perfect square you mean a square number, i.e. $n$ is a perfect square, if there exists a number $m$ such that $n=m^2$?

Comment: Yes I do mean that. For example $2^2+5^1=9=3^2$

Comment: There is a second solution check out the edit to my original answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if $2^a+5^b=w^2$, then $2^a \equiv w^2 \pmod 5$. This implies that $2\mid a$. So let $c\in\Bbb{N}\space|\space 2c=a$.
$$2^{2c}+5^b=w^2$$
$$5^b=w^2-2^{2c}$$
$$5^b=(w-2^c)(w+2^c)$$
both $w-2^c$ and $w+2^c$ are both powers of $5$ so $\exists \space s,t\in\Bbb{N}\space|\space b=s+t, s>t,\space 5^s=w+2^c,5^t=w-2^c$
$$5^s=w+2^c\space\space\space(1)$$
$$5^t=w-2^c\space\space\space(2)$$
subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ we get
$$5^s-5^t=2^{c+1}\space\space\space(3)$$
$$5^t(5^{s-t}-1)=2^{c+1}\space\space\space(4)$$
$5\nmid 2^{c+1}$ so $t=0$ and $s=b$. Therefore
$$5^b-1=2^{c+1}\space\space\space(5)$$
$$5^b-5+2^2=2^{c+1}\space\space\space(6)$$
$$5^b-5=2^{c+1}-2^2\space\space\space(7)$$
$$5(5^{b-1}-1)=2^2(2^{c-1}-1)\space\space\space(8)$$
$5\mid $lhs of (8) $\Rightarrow$ $5\mid $rhs of (8). $5\nmid 2^2$ so $5 \mid 2^{c-1}-1 \Rightarrow 4 \mid c-1$

lhs of (8) $\equiv 0,20,27\pmod {31}$ and rhs of (8) $\equiv 0,4,12,28,29\pmod {31}$

The only way for the equation to be equal is if both sides are divisible by 31.

$31\nmid 2^2$ therefore $31\mid 2^{c-1}-1 \Rightarrow 5 \mid c-1$

Combining both of the facts that $4 \mid c-1$ and $5 \mid c-1\Rightarrow 20\mid c-1\Rightarrow 25 \mid 2^{c-1}-1\Rightarrow 25\mid $rhs of (8)$\Rightarrow 25\mid $lhs of (8) $\Rightarrow  5\mid 5^{b-1}-1\Rightarrow b=1$

plugging in $1$ for $b$ in $(5)$ implies that $c=1\Rightarrow a=2$

the first solution is $a=2$, $b=1$, $w^2=9$

**Edit:** In the beginning of the proof I assumed that $2^a\equiv w^2 \pmod 5$. This is true iff $b\neq 0$.

If $b=0$ then $2^a+1=w^2$
$$2^a+1=w^2$$
$$2^a=w^2-1$$
$$2^a=(w-1)(w+1)$$
both $w-1$ and $w+1$ are both powers of $2$ so $\exists \space u,v\in\Bbb{N}\space|\space a=u+v, u>v,\space 2^u=w+1,2^v=w-1$
$$2^u=w+1\quad(9)$$
$$2^v=w-1\quad(10)$$
subtracting $(10)$ from $(9)$ we get
$$2^u-2^v=2\quad(11)$$
$$2^v(2^{u-v}-1)=2\quad(12)$$
This implies $v=1$ and both sides of (12) can be divided by 2 
$$2^{u-1}-1=1\quad(13)$$
$$2^{u-1}=2\quad(14)$$
$$u-1=1\quad(15)$$
$$u=2\quad(16)$$
This gives the second solution $a=3$, $b=0$, $w^2=9$

**Edit 2: too long for comment, answering Prathmesh's question from the comment below**

After getting to equation to $(8)$ I knew that if I could show that $5 \mid 5^{b-1}-1$ then there would only be one solution to that portion of the problem. Working backwards $25 \mid 2^{c-1}-1$. powers of $2$ have a cycle of $20 \pmod{25}$. So $25 \mid 2^{c-1}-1$ iff $20 \mid c-1$. I already had $4 \mid c-1$ from the fact that both sides of $(8)$ are divisible by $5$. So I needed a mod that produces cycle that is a multiple of $5$ in powers of $2$. In general if a mod will produce a cycle $x$ if the mod is divisible by a sufficiently large power of of $x$ or is divisible by a prime factor that is of the form $xk+1$. So the mod in this case needs to have a sufficiently large power of of $5$ or has a prime factor of the form $5k+1$. Since I am trying to prove that the rhs is divisable by $25$ I can't use powers of $5$ so I am left with numbers that have a prime factor of the form $5k+1$. All primes except $2$ are odd so I can just look at numbers of the form $10k+1$. So I first tried $11$ but both sides can be $\equiv 1,3,4,5,9\pmod{11}$. $21$ has a prime factorization of $3$ and $7$ neither of which is of the form $10k+1$. so then I tried $31$.

Comment: What was the motivation for taking mod $31$ in finding the first solution?

Comment: @Prathmesh The answer to your mod 31 question is in an edit of my original post because the answer was too long for the comment section.

Answer (score 4):

If $2^a+5^b = m^2$, then $m^2\equiv 0, 1, 4\pmod{5}$. $0$ is impossible since $2^a$ is never divisible by 5, so $2^a+5^b\equiv 2^a \equiv 1, 4\pmod{5}$. This implies that $a$ is even, say $a=2k$. This gives $5^b = m^2-2^{2k} = (m-2^k)(m+2^k)$, which implies that both $m-2^k$ and $m+2^k$ are powers of $5$, say
$$m-2^k = 5^r,\ m+2^k=5^s, r<s\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2^{k+1} = 5^s-5^r.$$
But $5^s-5^r$ is divisible by 5 for $r>0$, so it cannot be a power of two unless $r=0$.

Thus any solution must have $m=2^k+1$, $m+2^k = 5^b$, so that $5^b = 2^{k+1}+1$, or $5^b-2^{k+1}=1$. By [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), either $b\le 1$ or $k+1\le 1$. Since $b$ is a positive integer, we get $b=1$, whence $2^{k+1}=4$ and $k=1$, so $a=2$.

Comment: Wait how is $a$ even. Note that I wrote that a is not necessarily even. Am I wrong? Please read the last comment above and let me know. Thank You

Comment: Edited. See above.

Comment: How is $5^s-5^r$ 5 mod 10? powers of 5 end in 5. So, wouldn't subtracting 2 powers of 5 (assuming power=0) result in a number that is 0 mod 10. Moreover, what is Mihailescu's Theorem?

Comment: Corrected, but a minor point. As for Mihailescu's Theorem, look up Catalan's Conjecture (they are the same; Mihailescu proved the conjecture).

Answer (score 1):

Here is at least a partial solution to your problem. $2^a+5^b\mod 2=1$ no matter what $a,b$ you choose. Thus $2^a+5^b$ is an odd number. Now squares of even numbers are even and squares of odd numbers are odd. Thus, if $2^b+5^b$ is a square, it is the square of an odd number. The last digit of a square of an odd number has to be one, five or nine. Since $2^a+5^b\mod 5$ is either $2$ or $4$ and $1,5,9\mod 5 = 1,0,4$. Moreover, $2^a+5^b\mod 5 =4$ if and only if $a$ is even. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Hm! Why $2^a+5^b\mod 5$ is either 2 or 4? If $a=4, b=1$ then $2^a+5^b = 1 \mod 5$

Comment: Well, I think that $2^a+5^b$ can be any number between 1 and 4. But since as @James showed $1, 5, 9 \mod 5 = 1, 0, 4$ we should consider only 1 and 4. $2^a+5^b=1(\mod 5)$ if $a=4k$ and $2^a+5^b=1(\mod 5)$ if $a=2+4k$ for $k\in\mathbb N_0$

Comment: @James note that $2^a+5^b \equiv 2^a\pmod{5}.$ If $a=1$ then it is $2$, if $a=2$ then it is $4$, if $a=3$ then it is $3$ if a is $4$ then it is $1$.

The only number $2^a$ mod 5 can't be is 0. 

I actually got up to this point. The reason I was unable to go further was because I noted that $2^a$ cycles only $4$ times in $\pmod 5$ not $5$ so, you can't really deduce that $a$ is even. Do you see why?

Comment: $a$ is even because of Fermat's theorem: $2^{4k}=1\mod 5$ since 2 and 5 are coprime

Comment: Very well. Thank You. I forgot about Fermat's Little Theorem.