# Solutions of $2^a+5^b=c^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I tried to solve this question using this way:
$a$ must be even, because if it's odd the equation have no solution. Let $a=2n$, so
\begin{align*}
2^{2n}+5^b &= c^2 \\
(2^n)^2+5^b &= c^2 \\
5^b &= c^2-(2^n)^2 \\
5^b &= (c-2^n)(c+2^n)
\end{align*}

Only one of $c-2^n$ and $c+2^n$ can be divided by 5, $c-2^n \neq c+2^n$, so $c-2^n=1$ and $c+2^n=5^b$.
From this equations, I got $1+2^{n+1}=5^b$.
But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Randall: If $a$ is odd, then the solution fails mod $4$.

Comment: a, b, and c are integers.If $a$ is odd, then the last digit of $2^a$ is 2 or 8. Added by 5, we got 7 or 3. There is no integer $c$ such that the last digit of $c^2$ is 7 or 3. I forgot to state that the solutions must be integer.

Comment: Got it.  My fault.

Comment: @Randall: Took me a second to see it too!

Comment: Well, you could use [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: If $n=1,$ you get a solution $4+5=9.$ If $n \geq 2,$ it follows that the exponent $b$ is also even, as odd squares are $1 \pmod 8,$ meaning $5^{2k+1} \equiv 5 \pmod 8.$ Put it all together, any other solutions are primitive Pythagorean triples. I guess that is the point of Robert's comment...

Comment: @Will: But how to got the solutions after we know that $b$ is even?

Comment: @Robert: For $b=1$, we got a solution. For $b>1$, by the Theorem, it has no solution. Am I right?

Comment: With both $a,b$ even, we get coprime parameters $r,s,$ not both odd, such that $2rs = 2^{a/2}$ and $r^2 - s^2 = 5^{b/2}.$ Since $r,s$ are coprime, this means $s=1$ and $r= 2^w$ for some $w.$ In turn, this means that $r^2$ is a power of $2$ that differs from a power of $5$ by exactly $1.$ Hence Catalan's conjecture. Of course, for te specific primes $2,5,$ there are elementary ways to prove that the only powers differing by $1$ are $5-4.$ Elementary, but long.

Comment: See also: [Find all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $2^a+5^b$ is a perfect square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2960232)

Answer (score 3):

Continue from your work, we solve $$1+2^{n+1} = 5^b$$
This special case of Catalan equation is easy: $2$ is a primitive root of $25$, hence a primitive root for any $5^b$. Therefore
$$2^{n+1} \equiv -1 \pmod{5^b}$$
implies $n+1$ is divisible by $\varphi(5^b)/2 = 2(5^{b-1})$, so $n+1 \geq 2(5^{b-1})$.
Hence $$5^b \geq 1+2^{2(5^{b-1})}$$
the RHS grows far faster than LHS, the inequality only holds when $b=1$.

---

Therefore all solution to your original equation $2^a+5^b=c^2$ is $(a,b,c)=(2,1,3)$.

Comment: Another approach. Thanks. But, could you explain why "$2$ is a primitive root of $25$" implies "$2$ is primitive root for any $5^b$"?

Comment: @AgungIzzulHaq  The following result is well-known: if $b$ is a primitive root for $p^2$, then $b$ is a primitive root for any $p^n$, $n\geq 2$.